# Can not import large SQL dump into MySQL 5.6

Tags: mysql

I dumped a large database into a SQL file that contains large BLOB attachments for a table. When doing the dump I turned on hex-blobs, and I've done this dump many times before without any problems.

The dump was done using a MySQL 5.1 database.

I now have a clean install of MySQL 5.6 and can not import this SQL file. The file itself is about 13GB and it fails each time at the same line.

```
mysql --user=root --password=xxxx --database=budgets_3 < budgets_3.sql
Warning: Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
ERROR 2006 (HY000) at line 3251: MySQL server has gone away
```

MySQL is **not** restarting or crashing.
I've look at the SQL file using a text for large files and can not see anything wrong. Except that the `insert` statement is very large.
I have run the import on the CLI and in MySQL Workbench but both fail.
I've set the `max_allowed_packet=128M` but still does not work (should be more than enough).

Here is a paste of the top part of the SQL file.

```
-- MySQL dump 10.13  Distrib 5.1.72, for Win64 (unknown)
--
-- Host: localhost    Database: nosweatbudgets_3
-- ------------------------------------------------------
-- Server version   5.1.72-community

/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;
/*!40103 SET @OLD_TIME_ZONE=@@TIME_ZONE */;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00' */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
/*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;
```

This is from my workstation which I am in the process of trying to update to MySQL 5.6, and if I can't fix this I'll have to take a dump from the production server. Which will take many hours to download so I'd like to see if I can get this working here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran this query to see what the real value of `max_allowed_packet` was when running the import.

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'max%';
```

I discovered that MySQL Workbench 6.x was not restarting MySQL after changing the configuration file. As a result my attempts to resolve the problem were not working.

After restarting MySQL the import operation worked successfully.

In addition, I read that `max_allowed_packet` is a setting used in both the server and client. If you experience this problem then make sure you set it in the server configuration, and on the client. To set on the client like this `mysql --max_allowed_packet=64M` in the command line.

The problem is that the server can disconnect if the packet is too large, and also the MySQL client can disconnect if the packet is too large.

This is discussed here in the manual.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/packet-too-large.html